# Google App Engine ndb Simple Query gives NeedIndexError

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have a Google App Engine project that uses python 2.7, and Cloud Datastore (well it may be Cloud Firestore but more on that later). My issue is that when I do a simple query e.g. `Data.query(ndb.AND(Data.timeStamp >= day, Data.timeStamp < day + datetime.timedelta(days=1))).order(Data.timeStamp)` I get a 500 (server error) and this error in the logs:
*NeedIndexError: no matching index found.

The suggested index for this query is:

- kind: Data

  properties:

  - name: timeStamp*
That suggested index is an index for a simple query. If I go add that query to the index.yaml file and run `gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml`, I get this message:
*ERROR: (gcloud.datastore.indexes.create) Server responded with code [400]:

  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400.

  Creating a composite index failed for entity_type: "Data"

Property {

  name: "timeStamp"

  direction: ASCENDING

}

ancestor: false

: This index:
IndexDef{semantics=DATASTORE, kind=Data, indexAncestor=NONE, propertyDefs=[PropertyDef{path=timeStamp, mode=ORDERED, direction=ASCENDING}]}

is not necessary, since single-property indexes are built in.*
So I cannot run this query because I need an index, but I am not allowed to make the index. So my question is, how do I run this query?
More info:
Not sure but this may be relevant: When I go into the Google Cloud Console (console.cloud.google.com) and click on the Datastore tab it claims that I use "Cloud Firestore in Native mode" and gives me a link to the Firestore tab. When I go there I can see all my data in Firestore. All this happens even though I use python2 and the ndb api to access Cloud Datastore/Firestore.
Also, when I click on the index page in the Firestore tab, GCP claims that all of my fields are indexed for simple queries.
Finally, the dev_appserver.py did not generate the index for me in the index.yaml file (as expected).
Here is my code:
main.py

```py
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Data(ndb.Model):
    timeStamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True)


#WSGI compatible function
def app(env, startResponse):

    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]
    status = "200 OK"

    path = env["PATH_INFO"]

    if path == "/doData":

        Data(timeStamp = datetime.datetime.now()).put()

        startResponse(status, headers)
        return ["done"]


    elif path == "/getData":

        day = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-06-28", "%Y-%m-%d")

        records = Data.query(ndb.AND(Data.timeStamp >= day, Data.timeStamp < day + datetime.timedelta(days=1))).order(Data.timeStamp).fetch(10)
        print(records)

        startResponse(status, headers)
        return [str(record.timeStamp) + "\n" for record in records]


    startResponse("404 NOT FOUND", headers)
    return ["404 Page Not Found"]
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

index.yaml:

```
indexes:

- kind: Data
  properties:
  - name: timeStamp

# AUTOGENERATED

# This index.yaml is automatically updated whenever the dev_appserver
# detects that a new type of query is run.  If you want to manage the
# index.yaml file manually, remove the above marker line (the line
# saying "# AUTOGENERATED").  If you want to manage some indexes
# manually, move them above the marker line.  The index.yaml file is
# automatically uploaded to the admin console when you next deploy
# your application using appcfg.py.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra info is indeed relevant. Your project uses Cloud Firestore in Native mode and not Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode:

```
When I go into the Google Cloud Console and click on the Datastore tab it claims that I use "Cloud Firestore in Native mode" and gives me a link to the Firestore tab.
```

If you want to use NDB and the Cloud Datastore API, you'll need to create a new project and select Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode when you [create your database](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/quickstart#create_a_database).

If you continue using this project, you should use one of the [Cloud Firestore client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/libraries) instead.